# Wordpress resets plugin settings when migrating

Tags: wordpress, settings, reset

I am migrating a wordpress site from one domain to the other.Plugins lose my preferences in the process.I really don't understand why.I'm curious as to why this happens.

Here are the steps i went through:

```
1. uploaded wordpress files from localhost 
   through FTP on the new domain ( http://example-live.com )
2. uploaded database to the new domain
3. changed all links referring to http://localhost to http://example-live.com
4. treated text_widgets differently because they are serialized in the db.
5. edited .htaccess
6. updated wp_config.php
```

Pages display normally but I am missing plugin preferences...Any thoughts ?

Edit: Found this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I decided to automate the process and used the Wordpress Duplicator Plugin (free) which can be found here http://lifeinthegrid.com/labs/duplicator/.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace all your links in your sql dump **before** import :

Open your SQL dump with a text editor and replace all local URLs with your domain URL (eg. replace all "`localhost/mysite`" with "`www.yourdomain.com`"), as described here : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/exporting-and-importing-wordpress

EDIT : Be careful with serialized data, you cannot simply replace `localhost/mysite` with a shorter/longer string, you'll have to handle this manually

Comment: why does it need to be done before step 2 ? What is the reason ?

Comment: You have to modify your sql dump before importing it on new server, otherwise it is useless